# TABLE(RESULT_SCAN()) is behaving differently for Clustered Inserts

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to fetch record counts from table(result_scan()) for clustered tables.

Table - 1 : clustered by 1 key
`select sum("number of rows inserted") from TABLE(RESULT_SCAN(query_id))`. This worked and gave back record count.

Table -2 : clustered by 2 keys. 
Could not execute the record count query: 
`select sum("number of rows inserted") from TABLE(RESULT_SCAN(query_id)). Error Message obtained is 000904 (42000): 01929f09-01a8-3a2c-0000-54ad005bcfc2: SQL compilation error: error line 1 at position 11
invalid identifier '"number of rows inserted"'`

Not sure why the same query works in one scenario and throws invalid identifier in another?

Comment: Are you sure that the query_id that you're plugging into the RESULT_SCAN actually had inserted records...or the "number of rows inserted" field?

Comment: Maybe try just a SELECT * instead?  Not sure why you are running a SUM there.

Comment: We load a group of similar files using external stage in a single transaction and to get   total record count we are using SUM.

Comment: the query id associated with insert/copy is finishing successfully. We are doing  a POC and trying to understand how the RESULT_SCAN works for various load types i.e upsert, insert and insert into clustered tables.

Comment: So, each of your queries above are for COPY INTO statements?  My suggestion regarding the SELECT * is to make sure that the query_id's that you are requesting a RESULT_SCAN of actually returns a column called "number of rows inserted".  That's the first thing to look at.  That the table is clustered by 2 keys has nothing to do with the RESULT_SCAN results.

Answer (score 0):

As I see, the COPY command does not return the "number of rows inserted" column. If you want to get the number of rows inserted by COPY command, you should sum the rows_loaded column:

```
select sum("rows_loaded") from TABLE(RESULT_SCAN());
```

Please check: https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table.html#output